# ADS1115 ADC input filter - active or passive?

Tags: voltage, adc, filter, measurement, active-filter

I want to implement an ADC as part of my bachelor's thesis.

The datasheet of the ADS1115 show that there is no filtering done by the ADC chip before the multiplexer. As I read [here,](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/practical-filter-design-precision-adcs.html) it is good practice to use a filter before the input.

[image]

I am currently trying to decide on what kind of filtering would be best for the ADS1115 inputs.

I read online from some people that passive lowpass filtering should do just fine.

I remember my professor stating in a lecture that active filtering in general is simply better than passive filtering.

In any case I would appreciate any input.

Comment: It needs to be an anti-alias filter and that depends a lot on what multiplexing regime you are going to use and how much of the aliasing artefacts you are prepared to allow through to baseband.

Comment: If your signal is actually above 300Hz you should probably choose a different ADC than the ADS1115 which is limited to well under 1kHz sample rate. Nyquist (2x) is a theoretical minimum but going much higher will likely simplify your life.

Comment: "is simply better" is – wrong. It can achieve better filter characteristics, yes, but also introduces active components, which leads to noice. Golden rule of engineering: "simply better" almost never exists; there is always a *reason* why something is *better in a given use case*. Personally, active filters not being *that* common should tell you something... Filtering is done with relatively relaxed passive filters by using a sampling rate that's higher than necessary for your signal of interest and allows for less strict filters. The rest is done digitally – much easier, cheaper and reliable

Comment: for incredibly low frequencies like the one you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summary:

1. A band pass of 300Hz to 1MHz won't do you any good - the ADS1115 can only sample at maximum 860 samples per second.
2. You cannot capture a signal above 400 Hz with the ADS1115.
3. TI recommends a simple RC low pass filter to reduce aliasing.
4. An RC low pass is adequate because the ADS1115 samples at a much higher rate and decimates and filters down to the set output sampling rate.

---

Details:

As always, start with the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115.pdf)

The ADS1115 will be of no use for a signal between 300 Hz and 1MHz.  It has a maximum data rate of 860 samples per second - that's just about adequate for signals up to between 300 and 400 Hz.  Above that you will get aliasing and a much reduced signal level.  In other words, you can sample signals up to about 400Hz with the ADS1115.

All you need is a low pass.

On page 33, you will find this recommendation:

> A first-order resistor-capacitor (RC) filter is (in most cases) sufficient to either totally eliminate aliasing, or to reduce the effect of aliasing to a level within the noise floor of the sensor. Ideally,any signal beyond fMOD/ 2 is attenuated to a level below the noise floor of the ADC.  The digital filter of the ADS111x attenuate signals to a certain degree,as shown in Figure21. In addition,noise components are usually smaller in magnitude than the actual sensor signal. Therefore, use a first-order RC filter with a cutoff frequency set at the output data rate or 10x higher as a generally good starting point for a system design.

fMod is the modulation frequency of the delta-sigma converter in the chip.  It is the effective sampling rate that the signal "sees."  In the ADS1115, fMod is 250kHz.  To avoid aliasing, you need to reduce signal content above 125kHz.

The ADS1115 has digital filtering to remove stuff between the final (output) sampling rate and fMod/2.

An effective filter starts at your selected sampling rate.  If you are sampling at 860 samples per second, the you need an RC low pass with a cut off of 860 Hz.  For example, 1.6k and 100nF provides a cutoff of 884Hz and an attenuation of about 45dB at 125kHz.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118267/discussion-on-answer-by-jre-ads1115-adc-input-filter-active-or-passive).

Comment: Texas Instruments support team recommends to start the filter at 10x the sample rate instead of directly at the sample rate. Also they recommend the resistor to be less than 1k to avoid voltage errors. What do you think?.

Comment: JRE, why did you recommended a cut off of 860 Hz? shouldnt' it be half of that to achieve Nyquist rate?

Comment: @bardulia:  Nope.  The ADS1115 has a built in filter.  It oversample, filters, then decimates to the output data rate.  The RC filter only has to be effective for the oversampling frequency, not for the output data rate.  The ADS1115 oversamples at 250kHz.  The datasheet recommends that the cutoff for the RC filter be set to the data rate or 10 times higher.

Comment: @JRE thanks a lot for the clarification! it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

use TI’s Active filter design or Falstad’s [www.Falstad.com/afilter](http://www.Falstad.com/afilter) for a start. Choose Bessel and don’t be stingy on the orders. A quad analog Op Amp with a GBW > Q^2*GBW(of design) can do an 8th order Bessel filter for best group delay or Chebychev for steepest slope but terrible group delay near the breakpoint of -3 dB.

Define your worst case noise spectrum and expected SNR in and out then choose f-3dB around 1/3 of sampling rate or less.

Explain this to your advisor and see if they understand.

Comment: How should I choose when it comes to selecting the opamp? What parameters should I take into consideration? I have a lot of "NE5532AD8G"s laying around. Could I use those?

Comment: @EmreMUTLU answered by literally the first half of the first sentence of Tony's answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the NE5532AD8G doesnt show on the listed op-amps when you click on "Select alternate op-amp" on the TI desinger...

Comment: well, then it's probably not a suitable alternative :) (this is your bachelor thesis. You might need to buy 2€ worth of opamps if you're designing active filters for some reason. this will be among the cheapest things you do. )

Comment: I have yet to find my GBW formula written down anywhere. But this affects your response accuracy. Take Note.  An active filter ADC might be 10% of what I would  expect for a thesis. That’s a days work

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 oh itsn't the subject of my bachelors thesis. I just need an ADC as a sub-circuit.

Comment: That's probably because TI don't want to advertise somebody else's opamp as a suitable alternative to their own! (Who owns Signetics now?) 5532's are good, low noise, fast, but probably consume more power than you'd like. If you give them enough supply voltage (see their datasheet) they'll be fine.

Comment: ON semi makes NE parts now. It’s fine as a simple BJT 10MHz GBW

Comment: @Tony, seems like overkill for the typical ADC application? how often do you need to squeeze out the last drop, in bits and bandwidth?

Comment: when you have 40 dB SNR in and want 1 bit noise coming out with a 16 bit ADC without aliasing. But true most people don't really are about high  SNR

Comment: well -40dB noise is not unusual. (with poor luck,  near sampling freq...) 1bit/16bits is often a fallacious expectation, probably for this reason.

Comment: Did you ever hear of a brick filter used for telephony? Dou know how much SNR has been lost from the 8 bit analog compander to digital cell phone quality.. my guess about a 40 dB loss of SNR from my former expertise in telephony

Comment: no i did not, but I can hear it! I figured that was the compression vs the sampling. The 8bit must be faster?

Comment: Nope it’s 8bit with u or A law log compression with over 70 dB SNR ideal. 8kHz on 3kHz BW or 75% of Nyquist rate.. that needs a special brick filter

Comment: Why do you doubt ?

Comment: I don't, just trying to understand the comparison / get you to say some more details =)  . Did the special filter introduce a delay to fix phase?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer by @JRE above, and/or bring up a caveat for discussion:  Because it is a sigma-delta, there is a more to the story than just saying "it internally samples at 250kHz".

note: I am not 100% confident of my understanding of this but someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Look at Figure 21 in the [ADS111x datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1114.pdf), page 12. This is a typical pattern of the sinc or sinc^n filtering of sigma-delta ADC's. This graph appears to be a sinc^1.

Look at 6Hz: it is -10dB. Nyquist (vs the "output" rate of 8Hz in the example) is 4Hz, so anything at 6Hz will alias to 2Hz with -10dB attenuation! Look at 8Hz: it is that notch at -35dB, which is okay but hardly great. It will alias to DC or close to it!!! Unless you are sure there is no unwanted signal at these frequencies, it has to be fixed on the front end, i.e. analog filter.

Again the example presented by the TI datasheet was all at 8Hz output sampling rate. That sinc filter response will shift with the output sampling rate (not f_mod). Some ADC's have a steeper sinc^n than others. For example, this [TI app note](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/precisionhub/archive/2015/10/02/the-delta-sigma-advantage-to-anti-aliasing-filters) shows a sinc^3 in its Figure 3.

here's an in depth [app note](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/fundamental-principles-behind-sigma-delta-adc-topology-part2.html#) on the subject